# Get python sqlite to support latest sqlite version 3.25

Tags: python, sqlite, anaconda

I am using anaconda python v3.6 on Windows 10.

It supports sqlite version 3.21. I would like to get it to support the latest sqlite version 3.25 to make use of the latest features like windows functions.

How can the python version in anaconda be upgraded to support sqlite v3.25?

Comment: https://bugs.python.org/issue34916 I believe you have to wait.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sqlite3 for windows has been updated to sqlite 3.25 recently:
https://anaconda.org/anaconda/sqlite/files